# Controlling the quality "of x process" vs "of the x process"

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I'm working on a project for which I originally put the title as:

> Methods for controlling the quality of PET bottle manufacturing process.

However, now that I re-read it, I feel like its way more natural to say "of the PET bottle manufacturing process".

I would normally go with the second variant, but is the original version grammatically correct too?

Comment: For headlinese, shorter is a must. For a research paper, you can afford another three-letter word. Or "... the quality of PET bottle manufacturing." Manufacturing is indeed the manufacturing process.

Comment: If it's "headlinese," I would omit the other usage of "the" and try to shorten it further. Otherwise, it's a count singular noun, so it needs a determiner like "the."

Comment: Is it a specific process (that of a specific company or a specific named process invented by someone) or are you looking to improve bottle manufacture in general regardless of the details? That will affect the article. (I agree you can omit articles in titles, but I'm not sure if you're asking what is grammatical in normal use.)

Answer (score 1):

This would be a valid title:

> *Quality control in PET bottle manufacturing*

"Methods" doesn't really add much at all, nor does "process". All QC involves methods, and all manufacturing is a process.

Answer (score 0):

Broadly, either could be correct and including 'Methods for controlling…' is not helpful here.

'… the PET bottle manufacturing process' is one thing.

'… PET bottle manufacturing' is a different thing.

Both are correct; which would you prefer?